# Building Tensorflow v1.0

Tags: tensorflow

I found "@%ws%" in many of the build files. For example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/third_party/curl.BUILD

Build Error:
Invalid label: invalid repository name '@%ws%': workspace names may contain only A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '-', '_' and '.'.

Linux / Bazel 0.4.5

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seeing this error when compiling TensorFlow at head or are you defining your own dependency in your workspace file?

"%ws%" should be automatically replaced with the right name when using the temp_workaround_http_archive rule (instead of the default Bazel http_archive rule) defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L74).

For the curl example you mentioned, that rule is used [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L459)

Comment: yes you are right i am amending the dependencies. ok i will amend the build file accordingly. thanks!